# Creating a Canvas on the web

Tags: html, canvas

I wanna creating canvas (scribble pad) where users can write something with a brush and i wanna save it and stream the same screen as an image to the other people. how can this be done on the web ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An Example](http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/)

[Creating an HTML 5 canvas painting application](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/)

[Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial)

[File saver API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#the-filesaver-interface)

[Google :)](http://www.google.com)